# Загрузка записей в TcxGridTableView

Tags: база-данных, delphi, gridview, devexpress

Каким способом можно загрузить данные в TcxGridTableView из базы, кроме стандартного присвоения значения колонкам в цикле по записям, получающимся в результате select'а к базе?

Проблема в том, что при большом количестве записей страницы с таким гридвью долго грузятся. Используется именно такой вариант, а нет DBTableView, потому что грид является редактируемым.

Comment: Вы пробовали обрамлять обновление данных в `BeginUpdate` / `EndUpdate` ?

Comment: "Используется именно такой вариант, а нет DBTableView, потому что грид является редактируемым.", а что мешает редактировать в DBTableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте DBTableView в связке с dxMemdata.
Т.е. выполняете select из базы и загружаете результаты запроса в dxMemdata, в которой данные можете редактировать как вам угодно.

dxMemdata.LoadFromDataSet() - загрузка данных в dxMemData

Comment: Спасибо за наводку

Answer (score 0):

Может лучше использовать связку dataset+datasource. Это лучший подход при работе с БД.